# Multiple JOINS with GROUP BY returning wrong data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, group-by

I have a MySQL database that have following tables
**sellers, product_additional, cart**

**Cart Columns**

```
id|user_id|product_id|quantity|seller_id
```

**Product Additional columns**

```
product_id|price|seller_id|stocks
```

**Sellers Columns**

```
user_id|store_name|latitude|longitude
```

**MySQL Function returns distance in KM**

`getDistance(lat1, long1,lat2, long2)`

**Problem**

I want that my query will return the sum of all product price from 5 different cheapest sellers, who are near 15 KM of the user address.

```
Price according to sellers in (product_additional table)

product_id|seller_id|price|stock
429       |1        |10   | 10
409       |1        |12   | 10
412       |1        |15   | 10
429       |2        |10   | 10
412       |2        |15   | 10
409       |2        |10   | 10
429       |3        |5    | 10
```

**1**: I have an array of product id for example: [429, 409]

**2**: Query will return only those sellers who have all the above product in their store (which is in additional product table)

**Expected Result**

```
Seller_id|price|
2        |20   |
1        |22   |
```

Please Note that I want only sellers that have both products 429, 409 in product_additional table, that's why seller with id=3 is not showing above.

**My Query**

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) as total_price, products_additional.seller_id
FROM `products_additional`
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id='3') as ucart ON `products_additional`.`product_id` = `ucart`.`product_id`
JOIN  (SELECT * FROM sellers WHERE getDistance(latitude, longitude,'28.413911','77.0423371') < 20 ) AS sellers ON `products_additional`.`seller_id`=`sellers`.`user_id`
JOIN (SELECT * FROM users WHERE activated='y') AS users ON `products_additional`.`seller_id`=`users`.`id`
WHERE `products_additional`.`stocks` >= `ucart`.`quantity`
AND `products_additional`.`product_id` IN('429', '409')
GROUP BY `products_additional`.`seller_id`
 LIMIT 5
```

Sometimes it return correct output, sometime it return wrong output, I'm unable to figure out what is wrong with this query. Anybody have some idea.

Hope You'll understand my problem :)

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with table structures and some sample data, and show desired result for this sample data strictly. *Sometimes it return correct output, sometime it return wrong output* Try to reproduce both variants by varying the parameters (for example, product id list).

Comment: Also, see about table and column aliases.

Comment: Please check if it is because of LIMIT 5, you may not be able to see all the records but only 5.

Comment: @AnupamChaplot, No it is not by LIMIT :(

Comment: @Akina, Okay I'll update the link of fiddle